# How to deal with null linq query result?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query in which i am getting the user list and after that we are getting the record by userid filter.

```
var user = UserDal.GetAllUsers().First(n => n.UsersID == 1);
```

But what should do if GetAllUsers() function returns null ? Should we check it by applying Any() ? Or something else ?

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault()  It's just for that purpose

Comment: GetAllUsers() should not return null. It should return a collection always, which may be empty.

Comment: What does the GetAllUsers() method look like?

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault. Should always return array or list (whatever) just needs to be empty if no results are returned. Like if you sql query a database it will return a dataset just with no rows.

Comment: Lot of `FirstOrDefault` answers. Do you really expect two users with the same ID?  If not, use `Single`.

Comment: @Rikon & others: if `GetAllUsers` returns `null` as opposed to an empty list, you'll get an exception on calling any method - including `FirstOrDefault`, or `Single`, or anything else. You have to have an object (even if it's an empty list) to call a method on it!

Comment: @Marc, I agree that Single (or SingleOrDefault) is perhaps more expressive of intent, but I usually fall toward the FirstOrDefault camp just because I'm under the impression that it was faster

Answer (score 3):

> But what should do if GetAllUsers() function returns null ?

If `UserDal.GetAllUsers` returns `null`, then you can't use `Any`, you will have to check it against `null`. You can only use `Any` or `FirstOrDefault` if the method returns a collection *(even empty)*.

If the method could return null then:

```
var temp = UserDal.GetAllUsers();
if(temp != null)
{
   var user = temp.FirstOrDefault(n=> n.UserID == 1);
}
```

If your method could return an empty collection instead of `null` then you can do:

```
var user = UserDal.GetAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(n => n.UsersID == 1);
```

You should modify your method `UserDal.GetAllUsers` to not return a null. If there are no records then an empty collection should be returned.

Comment: @Downvoter, could you please point to the mistake in answer ?

Comment: The method `GetAllUsers()` shouldn't really return null - it's responsibility is to return a collection. If you are returning null with it then I think you are doing it wrong.

Btw I'm not downvoter.

Comment: @rosko, yes it shouldn't. But if the OP is saying it is returning `null` then I would answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I agree but it's always better to add some additional information that gives a valid reason to not follow a solution like this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply check if it is null?

```
var users = UserDal.GetAllUsers();

if (users == null || !users.Any())
{
    // handle error
}

var user = users.First(x => x.Id == someId);
```

However, if you're in control of the code-base, I'd certainly say that you should make it so `GetAllUsers` never returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[DefaultIfEmpty]` and use that instance as default value: to handle null value

Answer (score 0):

You could use Monads, e.g. https://github.com/sergun/monads.net

Or you could implement your own extension methods.
This code is adapted from the original extension method and returns default(T) instead of throwing an exception.

```
// UserDal.GetAllUsers() returns null and user is null
var user = UserDal.GetAllUsers().MyFirstOrDefault(n => n.UsersID == 1);

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T MyFirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
         Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null) return default(T);
        if (predicate == null) return default(T);

        foreach (T element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element)) return element;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Or you could use null checks or ensure never to return null to safeguard against null reference exception when using the standard extension methods.